# Access - How to create a dropdown with all tables populated in subform?

Tags: forms, ms-access, subform

I have an access DB with around 20 tables. I'd like to create a form that has a dropdown menu of all my tables in it. When a table is selected, Im trying to get the subform to reflect the information from those tables.

Basically, instead of having to click and open each table, look through them within a form. Is this possible?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could call this sub to populate your dropdown menu:

```
Private Sub Add_Tables_To_DropdownMenu()
  Dim T As TableDef

  For Each T In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If (Left(T.Name, 4) <> "USys") And (T.Attributes = 0) Then
        Dropdownmenu0.AddItem T.Name
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Then you can set an event on change of the dropdown menu, and update the SourceObject of your subform based on the value selected:

```
Private Sub Dropdownmenu0_AfterUpdate()
    Subform1.SourceObject = "Table." & Dropdownmenu0.Value
End Sub
```